# How to find the line that pass throughs the center point in polygon in Python?

Tags: python, polygon, shapely

I have a polygon shape like this
[image]

And I want to find the red line from these array points
[image]

The points are

```
array = [[4095, 2660],
   [4035, 2660],
   [3956, 2666],
   [3881, 2678],
   [3810, 2695],
   [3740, 2718],
   [3656, 2748],
   [3601, 2771],
   [3710, 2767],
   [3722, 2763],
   [3803, 2736],
   [3870, 2719],
   [3946, 2704],
   [4017, 2697],
   [4098, 2695],
   [4095, 2660]]
```

I try to do it using Shapely but I can't and the point not be exactly like this. I can't use two coordinate to find it

Comment: Why is it this red line? What makes the difference to a vertical middle line parallel to the short edges?

Comment: have you tried [centerline](https://centerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Comment: You might want to read about a [polygon straight skeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_skeleton) because what you asked for is not trivial in the general case. If that is your need, then this post might help [How to compute Straight Skeletons using Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136143)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [pygeoops.centerline](https://pygeoops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pygeoops.centerline.html#pygeoops.centerline). It won't give the exact result you have drawn, as the centerline calculated e.g. won't touch the "ends" of the polygon. Nonetheless the result will be close or at least it will be a good start.

Disclaimer: I am the developer of [pygeoops](https://pygeoops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Code sample:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
import pygeoops
import shapely
import shapely.plotting

poly = shapely.Polygon(
    [
        [4095, 2660], [4035, 2660], [3956, 2666], [3881, 2678],
        [3810, 2695], [3740, 2718], [3656, 2748], [3601, 2771],
        [3710, 2767], [3722, 2763], [3803, 2736], [3870, 2719],
        [3946, 2704], [4017, 2697], [4098, 2695], [4095, 2660],
    ]
)

centerline = pygeoops.centerline(poly)
shapely.plotting.plot_polygon(poly)
shapely.plotting.plot_line(centerline)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Result: [result of plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gphBo.png)

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that. This is based only on assumptions and not on the properties of a "polygon". For example: are there always two parallel sides?